# R plotting dataframe and keeping track of factor to number conversion

Tags: r, dataframe, plot

He is my dataframe and its plot

```
   my_df <- data.frame(var_1= as.factor(sample(c(0,1), 10, replace = TRUE)),
                       var_2 = sample(1:20, 10, replace = TRUE),
                       var_3 = as.factor(sample(c('a','b', 'c'), 10, replace = TRUE)))
    plot(my_df)
```

So factors are getting converted to numeric values. How can I figure out map between factor value and its numeric representation? For example it looks like `var_3` have the following conversion is in place `a -> 1`, `b -> 2`, `c -> 3`.

Also can I display this conversion map on the graph?

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plot.data.frame` passes `...` arguments to `?pairs` which has a `labels` argument

```
my_df <- data.frame(var_1= as.factor(sample(c(0,1), 10, replace = TRUE)),
                    var_2 = sample(1:20, 10, replace = TRUE),
                    var_3 = as.factor(sample(c('a','b', 'c'), 10, replace = TRUE)))

plot(my_df, labels = LETTERS[1:3])
```

So just get a vector of labels and use that

```
f <- function(data, default = names(data), use.varname = TRUE) {
  default <- rep_len(default, ncol(data))

  sapply(seq_along(data), function(ii) {
    x <- data[, ii]
    if (is.factor(x)) {
      lbl <- paste(levels(x), seq.int(nlevels(x)), sep = ' -> ', collapse = '\n')
      if (use.varname)
        paste(default[ii], lbl, sep = '\n') else lbl
    } else default[ii]
  })
}

f(my_df, use.varname = FALSE)
# [1] "0 -> 1\n1 -> 2"  "var_2"  "a -> 1\nb -> 2\nc -> 3"


f(my_df, use.varname = TRUE)
# [1] "var_1\n0 -> 1\n1 -> 2"  "var_2"  "var_3\na -> 1\nb -> 2\nc -> 3"


plot(my_df, labels = f(my_df))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome solution, how can I retain variable name? I am looking through your code, but my R skills are limited

Comment: @user1700890 see edits, is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Worked perfectly, initially through warnings()!

Comment: @user1700890 what kind

Comment: `Warning messages:
1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  "use.varname" is not a graphical parameter`

Comment: are you passing `use.varname` thru `f` and not `plot`?

Answer (score 2):

A better option might be to use `ggpairs` that gives more information

```
library(GGally)
ggpairs(my_df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The integers corresponds to the levels of your factor. If you want a scatterplot as that reported in your example, you can simply set the labels for your axis using the axis function.

```
plot(as.numeric(my_df$var_3), as.numeric(as.vector(my_df$var_1)), axes = F)
axis(side = 1, labels = levels(my_df$var_3), at = 1:length(levels(my_df$var_3)))
axis(side = 2)
box()
```

[image]

Now, if you want a multi-plot result, you can do as follows.

```
par(mfrow=c(3,3))
for (i in 1:ncol(my_df)){
  for (j in 1:ncol(my_df)){
    if (i == j) {
      plot(1, cex = 0, ylim = c(0,2), xlim = c(0,2))
      text(1, 1, labels  = paste(names(my_df)[j]))
    } else {
      plot(as.numeric(my_df[,i]), as.numeric(my_df[,j]), axes = F, 
           xlab = names(my_df)[i], ylab = names(my_df)[j])
      if (is.factor(my_df[,i])){
        axis(side = 1, labels = levels(my_df[,i]), at = 1:length(levels(my_df[,i])))  
      } else {
        axis(side = 1)  
      }
      if (is.factor(my_df[,j])){
        axis(side = 2, labels = levels(my_df[,j]), at = 1:length(levels(my_df[,j])))  
      } else {
        axis(side = 2)  
      }
      box()
    }
  }
}
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

Definitely verbose and not very pretty, but as you can see the variable levels (class names) are retained and plotted at the axis ticks...

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to do it for whole dataframe at once or do I need to plot individual pairs?